# Compiling resources.qrc with QGIS 3.20 (could not find qt5_env.bat)

Tags: qgis-plugins, osgeo4w, compile, qgis-3

To compile `resources.qrc` file with `pyrcc5` we usually do

```
qt5_env.bat

py3_env.bat

pyrcc5 -o pathtoplugin\resources.py pathtoplugin\resources.qrc
```

using OSGeo4W Shell as described in many questions on GIS SE and SO.

So far, I never had issues doing so. However, now I am doing it the first time after installing the Standalone version of QGIS 3.20 (https://qgis.org/downloads/QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.20.2-1.msi), and it seems like `qt5_env.bat` is just not there anymore, and am getting `could not find qt5_env.bat` when trying to run it via OSGeo4W Shell. A search on my C:\ drive gave the following result:

[image]

It's there for all older QGIS 3 versions, but not for 3.20.

Of course, I can simply compile my `resources.qrc` using 3.18's OSGeo4W Shell or any other older version, but my question is:

**Am I missing something really simple or has there anything been changed in 3.20 and how can I compile `resources.qrc` using 3.20?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You no longer need to run `qt5_env.bat` and `py3_env.bat` (I guess). Just run

`pyrcc5 -o pathtoplugin\resources.py pathtoplugin\resources.qrc`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the hint ! It looks like qt5_env.bat and py3_env.bat disappeared with the switch from .exe to .msi installation files.
Batch file pyuic5.bat and pyrcc5.bat disappeared too but pyuic5.exe and pyrcc5.exe are still there.